# pd.dataframe error I can't merge two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Thanks for reading my question
and sorry for my short english :( but I'm desperate

```
def PriceData(market):

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ["날짜","시가총액","거래량","거래대금","상장주식수"])
    print(df)
    for ticker in market:
        print(ticker)
        time.sleep(1)
        price = stock.get_market_cap_by_date("20200301", "20200630", ticker, "m") ## 2020년3월~2021년3월
        #print(price)

        df=pd.concat([df,price])
        #df['날짜'] = price.index
        '''#df['시가총액'].replace(price['시가총액'])
        df['거래량'] = price['거래량']
        df['거래대금'] = price['거래대금']
        df['상장주식수'] = price['상장주식수']'''

    print((df.index))

    return df
```

I want to put the data from the other data frames in the empty data frame.

Then, I make empty dataframe
`df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ["날짜(date)","시가총액(market cap)","거래량(volume)","거래대금(trading value)","상장주식수(listed stock)"]) #Plz ignore korean.`

and make 4X4 frame 4 times

```
     print(ticker)
     time.sleep(1)
     price = stock.get_market_cap_by_date("20200301", "20200630", ticker, "m") ##
```

(market is list (' 005930 ' , ' 000660 ' , ~~, ~~)
and, stock.get_~~_date is function in pykrx that has date index and data consists of 4 different columns and 4 rows.

I want my final dataframe(F.D) has 0~12 index and original index from 'price dataframe' (date index) put on another columns final dataframe.

Then, my F dataframe is 5X4

First, `df['날짜(date)']=price.index` 
I do this because (original index from 'price dataframe' (date index) put on another columns final dataframe.)

and,`df=df.append(price) or  df=pd.concat([df,price])`

in first result, error ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (8)
like this
I don't know 4, 8 means

Second,
'''df=pd.concat([df,price])'''
I do this only except '''df['날짜(date)']=price.index '''

then,

```
            날짜(date)             시가총액(cap)        거래량(vol)            거래대금(trading value)       상장주식수(listed stock)
2020-03-31  NaN  285057116762500  856741868  42269216023680  5969782550
2020-04-30  NaN  298489127500000  424101937  20785194256247  5969782550
2020-05-31  NaN  302667975285000  374264673  18385574461984  5969782550
2020-06-30  NaN  315204518640000  517439261  27561492591886  5969782550
2020-03-31  NaN   60642597004500  149461339  12250642650756   728002365
2020-04-30  NaN   60933797950500   91942271   7587119131754   728002365
2020-05-31  NaN   59332192747500   83525536   6896381543378   728002365
2020-06-30  NaN   61953001261500   91590220   7928776009315   728002365
2020-03-31  NaN   32997756670000   88480559   3729532013613   822886700
2020-04-30  NaN   34766963075000   36541914   1533018958255   822886700
2020-05-31  NaN   35260695095000   38727541   1635376156236   822886700
2020-06-30  NaN   38264231550000   59384055   2758364553583   822886700
```

You can see behind '날짜(date)' NaN

But I do this `df['날짜(date)'] = price.index`

same error as first

what is matter??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8hg5.png) First code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Onj33.png) Second code

This is all of code

```
from pykrx import stock
import pandas as pd
import time
import numpy as np


def return_Name(market): #티커를 받으면 이름을 한 열의 df로 반환
    Market = []

    for ticker in market:
        Name = stock.get_market_ticker_name(ticker)

        Market.append([Name])

    df = pd.DataFrame(Market, columns=['회사명'])
    return df

def Fundamental(market):
    '''
    for ticker in market:
           print(ticker)
           time.sleep(1)
           df = stock.get_market_fundamental_by_date("20200301", "20200630", ticker, "m")
           print(df)

    return df  #해야됨.
'''
def PriceData(market):

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ["날짜","시가총액","거래량","거래대금","상장주식수"])
    print(df)
    for ticker in market:
        print(ticker)
        time.sleep(1)
        price = stock.get_market_cap_by_date("20200301", "20200630", ticker, "m") ## 2020년3월~2021년3월
        #print(price)

        df=pd.concat([df,price])
        #df['날짜'] = price.index
        '''#df['시가총액'].replace(price['시가총액'])
        df['거래량'] = price['거래량']
        df['거래대금'] = price['거래대금']
        df['상장주식수'] = price['상장주식수']'''

    print((df.index))

    return df

def main():

    #코스피 200을 불러오기 (인덱스:티커 열: 이름, 종가, 시가총액)
    KOSPI = stock.get_market_ticker_list(market="KOSPI")  # 변수 KOSPI에 KOSPI 전 종목 티커를 리스트 형태로 저장

    df = stock.get_market_cap_by_ticker('20200331', market="KOSPI")  # 2020년3월31일의 종가, 시가총액, 거래량, 거래대금, 상장주식수를 df형태로 저장 얘가 기본 df
    df = df.head(3)  # 상위 200
    dfNAME = return_Name(df.index)
    dfNAME.index = df.index  # 이름df의 index를 티커로 변경
    df = pd.concat([df, dfNAME], axis=1)  # 데이터프레임 병합
    df = df[['회사명', '종가', '시가총액']]  # df 회사명 순서 바꾸기 (필요한 데이터들로만 정리)

    # 분기별로 시가총애그 거래량, 거래대금, 상장주식수 불러오기.
    dfPrice=PriceData(df.index)

    print(dfPrice)



    #print(df)  #이건 df프린트
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable; we need your question to be self-contained, in keeping with the purpose of this site.

Comment: Sorry, I write all of my code to modify

Comment: @kubear: Will be nice if you can replace korean strings with english ones as simple as `A`, `B`, `C`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I translated it into parentheses.